# how to add text on image and move that text to different points(objective-c)

Tags: objective-c

I want to add text on image, not on a specific point but want to move it anywhere on the image. just like many photo editing apps. anybody know how to do this?

Comment: use this https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/zdstickerview

Comment: thanks @FahadJamal :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/kcandr/IQLabelView
This one is the best approach and it worked fine for me by making the required changes to the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can set label on UIImageView and then you can write whatever you want to write.

Comment: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/zdstickerview This one is a very simple and easy approach guys... suggested by @FahadJamal. Got the same thing i wanted